# How to create two separate layouts for 10'' and 9.7'' tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, screen-size

I'm developing an application for Android tablets. I've read this [Google's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) several times, but something justs doesn't seem right:

I've been testing the app on a Genymotion's Google Nexus 10 (10.1''). Yesterday I bought a 9.7'' tablet to test on a real device, but the **interface was as if I set the Android Studio layout preview to Nexus 9 (8.9'')**.

So I guessed this:

- More than 10'' is treated as `xlarge`.
- Less than 10'' is treated as `large`.

So I moved all my layouts to `/layout-xlarge-land/`
And began designing a new one to fit my 9.7'' tablet, and put into `/layout-large-land/`, basing in the 8.9'' Nexus 9 (that looked exactly as in my 9.7'')

But then my surprise was that Android Studio (or actually just Android) treats both 8.9'' (=9.7'') and 10'' as `large`.

I have tried several answers saying to rename the folder to `/layout-sw768dp/`, but they don't work.

So **I need two folders: one for 10'' tablets and another for 9.7''** (yes, they are not equally treated).

**How should I name them?**

Comment: Did you ever solve the riddle?  What swXXXdp folder did you go with to hit a 9.7" 2048x1536 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need two folders: one for 10'' tablets and another for 9.7''

Those are not meaningful figures, and therefore there is no means of having different resources for them. They are not meaningful, because they do not take aspect ratio into account. Not all Android devices have the same aspect ratio: some are 16:9, some are 16:10, some are 4:3, some are 1:1, some are other things entirely. 10", 9.7", and kin are primarily for marketing purposes.

This is no different than in Web design, where designers don't speak in terms of the diagonal dimension of a browser window all that much.

For technical purposes, while you can use the legacy `-large`/`-xlarge` sorts of qualifiers, they were supplanted about four years ago by the `-w`/`-h`/`-sw` qualifiers:

- `-w640dp` indicates resources that should only be used on devices whose current width is `640dp` (i.e., 4 inches) or larger, where you can supply the number you want where I have 640
- `-h640dp` indicates resources that should only be used on devices whose current height is `640dp` or larger (again, with customizable values)
- `-sw640dp` indicates resources that should only be used on devices whose smallest width, in any orientation, is `640dp` or larger (in landscape, the "smallest width" is actually the current height)

This gives you control much like how Web designers use media queries in CSS stylesheets to change CSS rules based on particular heights and widths.

Now, since nobody knows what you think is a 9.7" UI and what you think is a 10" UI, nobody can really help you either consolidate that into one set of layout rules or provide you with qualifier values that will work. You are going to need to determine for yourself where your dividing line is, based on current width, current height, or smallest width. Let's pretend for the moment that you choose 800dp current width as being your dividing line. Your smaller-than-800dp layouts would go in directories like `res/layout/` and `res/layout-land/`. Your 800dp-or-larger layouts would go in `res/layout-w800dp/`.

> I have tried several answers saying to rename the folder to /layout-sw768dp/, but they don't work.

You may wish to consider editing your question and explaining what "they don't work" means.

Comment: Thanks a lot, CommonsWare. I did not know screen size by inches wasn't a standard. I had to check both tablets and I found out that sthe big one (10.1'') was 1280 pixels, so I created ``layout-w1280dp-land`` and put there the larger layouts, exactly as you pointed out.

Comment: @jdarlan: The dimensions used in `res/layout-w1280dp-land/` are density-independent pixels (`dp`), not pixels, where `1dp` is 1/160th of an inch. Now, for a 10" tablet with 1280 width, its screen density probably is in the 160dpi bucket, which is why your math worked. But other screens will have other densities. Also `-w1280dp-land` is probably superfluous, unless you really plan on a different layout for `-w1280dp` where the device is in portrait but the current width is still 1280dp or larger.

Comment: I really don't understand your answer. "probably is in the 160dpi bucket" why is that? I don't know how to measure the density-independent pixels of a screen. I took the 1280 width from [here](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-3-10.1-inch_id7870), there also says 149 ppi, is that my number? Because I tried ``layout-w149dp-land`` and does not work. Also, why did my math worked? Again, thanks a lot, I'm learning so much.

Comment: @jdarlan: "I don't know how to measure the density-independent pixels of a screen" -- there are apps on the Play Store that can report this to you. Beyond that, use a ruler to measure the width and height in inches, then multiply each by 160 to get the width and height (approximately) in `dp`. "there also says 149 ppi, is that my number?" -- no. "ppi" is pixels per inch, also known as "dpi" (dots per inch). That is a statement of density, not a statement of size. [The documentation that you linked to](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) gets into this stuff.

Comment: @jdarlan: Note that `-w1280dp` says "use this layout for 1280dp **or larger**. 1528 > 1280, so a current width of 1528dp would be happy with a `-w1280dp` layout, if there's nothing higher than 1280dp available that is still less than 1528dp.

Comment: Okay, I don't know if I'm getting it. My smaller screen is 9.55 x 6.57 inches. So I do ``9.55 in * 160 = 1528 dp``.
Then, as that documentation states, I do this operation: ``px = dp * (dpi / 160)``, which is ``px = 1528dp * (132 ppi / 160)``. The result is 1260 px, so close to 1280, **which is why my math from the first comment** did work. I created ``layout-w1260dp-land`` and worked like a charm. Am I wrong in something?

Comment: @jdarlan: "Am I wrong in something?" -- `-w1260dp` is measured in `dp`, not `px`.

Comment: Then I honestly don't know anymore what to put in the ``-wXXXXdp``. Just the dp obtained from ``9.55 in * 160 = 1528``?  That is the width of my device in dp. That **should** work but it doesn't. What it works is ``-w1280dp``.

Comment: @jdarlan: "That is the width of my device in dp" -- no, that's the width that you are calculating based upon `9.55in`, and I don't know where you got that. [This free app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.dpiinfo) will tell you the exact width in `px` along with the density `dpi` bucket, so you can convert into `dp` to get the size in that unit. "That should work but it doesn't" -- and with that, I am going to sign off on this comment thread. In the future, you need to explain what your symptoms are, as I noted in the last paragraph of my original answer.